# strcat Vs strncat - When should which function be used?

Tags: c, string

Some static code analyzer tools are suggesting that all strcat usage should be replaced with strncat for safety purpose?

In a program, if we know clearly the size of the target buffer and source buffers, is it still recommended to go for strncat?

Also, given the suggestions by static tools, should strcat be used ever?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure about source buffer's size and that the source buffer contains a NULL-character terminating the string, then you can safely use strcat when the destination buffer is large enough.

I still recommend using strncat and give it the *size of the destination buffer - length of the destination string - 1*

Note: I edited this since comments noted that my previous answer was horribly wrong.

Comment: +1. I would underline that in some systems (BSD for example) the compiler warns you if you use 'size-generic' string manipulation functions (strcat, strcpy, etc...)

Comment: I think you mean "...give it the size of the destination buffer _minus the size of the string it already contains_"

Comment: This answer is dangerously wrong.  @Nemo got it closer, but I think still off by one. [Pankaj's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6502352/228539) appears accurate and is much detailed.  It must be 'size of the destination buffer - length of the destination string - 1' to appropriately avoid buffer overflows.  Though this does seem a silly choice in designing this function since it must inherently look for the null terminator before starting to copy anyways and could calculate length along the way so we don't have to do it twice.

Answer (score 15):

*Concatenate two strings into a single string.*

***Prototypes***

```
#include <string.h>

char * strcat(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);

char * strncat(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2, size_t n);
```

***DESCRIPTION***

The `strcat()` and `strncat()` functions append a copy of the null-terminated
 string s2 to the end of the null-terminated string s1, then add a terminating \0'.  The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the
 result.

The strncat() function appends not more than n characters from s2, and
 then adds a terminating \0'.

The source and destination strings should not overlap, as the behavior is
 undefined.

***RETURN VALUES***

```
 The `strcat()` and `strncat()` functions return the pointer s1.
```

***SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS***

The `strcat()` function is easily misused in a manner which enables malicious users to arbitrarily change a running program's functionality
 through a buffer overflow attack.

Avoid using `strcat()`.  Instead, use `strncat()` or `strlcat()` and ensure
 that no more characters are copied to the destination buffer than it can
 hold.

Note that `strncat()` can also be problematic.  It may be a security concern for a string to be truncated at all.  Since the truncated string
 will not be as long as the original, it may refer to a completely different resource and usage of the truncated resource could result in very
 incorrect behavior.  Example:

```
void
 foo(const char *arbitrary_string)
 {
         char onstack[8] = "";

 #if defined(BAD)
         /*
          * This first strcat is bad behavior.  Do not use strcat!
          */
         (void)strcat(onstack, arbitrary_string);        /* BAD! */
 #elif defined(BETTER)
         /*
          * The following two lines demonstrate better use of
          * strncat().
          */
         (void)strncat(onstack, arbitrary_string,
             sizeof(onstack) - strlen(onstack) - 1);
 #elif defined(BEST)
         /*
          * These lines are even more robust due to testing for
          * truncation.
          */
         if (strlen(arbitrary_string) + 1 >
             sizeof(onstack) - strlen(onstack))
                 err(1, "onstack would be truncated");
         (void)strncat(onstack, arbitrary_string,
             sizeof(onstack) - strlen(onstack) - 1);
 #endif
 }
```

***Example***

```
char dest[20] = "Hello";
char *src = ", World!";
char numbers[] = "12345678";

printf("dest before strcat: \"%s\"\n", dest); // "Hello"

strcat(dest, src);
printf("dest after strcat:  \"%s\"\n", dest); // "Hello, World!"

strncat(dest, numbers, 3); // strcat first 3 chars of numbers
printf("dest after strncat: \"%s\"\n", dest); // "Hello, World!123"
```

Comment: Hi, the side comments do not reflect the actual output of the program, as src was defined as World (uppercase W) and the output states world (lowercase w).

Comment: "The strcat() and strncat() functions append a copy of the null-terminated string s2 to the end " is not so for `strncat()`.  `s2` need not be a _null-terminated string_.  It is sufficient for `s2` to be a chracter array that may lack a _null character_.

Answer (score 1):

They don't do the same thing so they can't be substituted for one another. Both have different data models.

- A string for `strcat` is a null
  terminated string for which you (as the programmer) guarantee that it has enough space.
- A string for `strncat` is a sequence
  of `char` that is either terminated
  at the length you are indicating *or*
  by a null termination if it is
  supposed to be shorter than that
  length.

So the use of these functions just depends on the assumptions that you may (or want to) do about your data.

Answer (score 0):

Static tools are generally poor at understanding the circumstances around the use of a function. I bet most of them just warn for every strcat encountered instead of actually looking whether the data passed to the function is deterministic or not. As already mentioned, if you have control over your input data neither function is unsafe.

Though note that strncat() is slightly slower, as it has to check against '\0' termination and a counter, and also explicitly add it to the end. strcat() on the other hand just checks for '\0', and it adds the trailing '\0' to the new string by copying the terminator from the second string along with all the data.

Answer (score -3):

It's very simple strcat is used to  concatenate two strings , for example

```
String a= data 
String b = structures
```

If use perform strcat

```
Strcat(a, b)
```

then

```
a= data structures
```

But if you want to concatenate specific numer of word r elements then you can use strncat
Example if you want to concatenate only the first two alphabet lts of b into a then you have to write 
Strncat(a,b,2) 
(It means that you just cancatenate the fist two alphabets of b into a , and a becomes
a = data st