# How to concat two char * in C?

Tags: c, pointers, concatenation

I receive a char * buffer which have the lenght of 10.
But I want to concat the whole content in my struct which have an variable char *.

```
typedef struct{
    char *buffer;
  //..

}file_entry;

file_entry real[128];

int fs_write(char *buffer, int size, int file) {
   //every time this function is called buffer have 10 of lenght only
   // I want to concat the whole text in my char* in my struct
}
```

Something like this :

```
  real[i].buffer += buffer;
```

How can I do this in C ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, do the following (adjust and add error checking as you see fit)

```
// real[i].buffer += buffer; 

   // Determine new size
   int newSize = strlen(real[i].buffer)  + strlen(buffer) + 1; 

   // Allocate new buffer
   char * newBuffer = (char *)malloc(newSize);

   // do the copy and concat
   strcpy(newBuffer,real[i].buffer);
   strcat(newBuffer,buffer); // or strncat

   // release old buffer
   free(real[i].buffer);

   // store new pointer
   real[i].buffer = newBuffer;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strcat(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcat/) to concatenate strings.  Make sure you have allocated enough space at the destination!

Note that just calling `strcat()` a bunch of times will result in a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).  Keeping track of the total length in your structure (or elsewhere, if you prefer) will help you out with that.

Comment: Always use `strncat` (also included in the link above) and not `strcat`.

Comment: Always?  That seems a bit heavy-handed.  "Be careful" is always good advice, though - I'll agree with that.  Here's a question and some answers regarding when to use each: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491038/strcat-vs-strncat-when-should-which-function-be-used

Comment: If you do not know why you are using `strcat`, which is because the two buffers are under pre-determined guarantees, then you should always use `strncat`. Someone starting out in C will always be better off using `strncat` over `strcat` simply because the risk is not worth the unnoticeable reward. Considering what the benefit actually is, I would even argue that you are never going to actually benefit from it unless you're writing something incredibly low level and the pre-requisite checks have already been done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear. Do you want:

- to concatenate every one of the 10 character buffers you receive into one array, pointed at by one `real[0].buffer`, or
- do you want each 10 character buffer to be pointed at by a different `real[i].buffer`, or
- something else?

You will need to allocate enough space for the copy of the buffer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//...
int size = 10+1; // need to allocate enough space for a terminating '\0'
char* buff = (char *)malloc(size);   
if (buff == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate %d bytes in file: %s, line %d\n",
                     size, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
    exit(1);
}
buff[0] = '\0';    // terminate the string so that strcat can work, if needed
//...
real[i].buffer = buff;  // now buffer points at some space
//...
strncpy(real[i].buffer, buffer, size-1);
```