# Concat two strings in C and allocate dynamically buffer

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I know this kind of question has already been asked. I also used the solution of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746866/how-to-concat-two-char-in-c) to my tests. However, I want to know **how** using this kind of function without memory leak neither exception.

Note: 
`LPTSTR` ~ `char*` and 
`LPCTSTR` ~ `const char*`

```
void add_to_buffer(LPTSTR* buffer, LPCTSTR msg) {
    // Determine new size
    int newSize = 0;

    // Allocate new buffer
    if (*buffer == NULL)
        newSize =  _tcsclen(msg) + 1; // strlen()
    else
        newSize = _tcslen(*buffer) + _tcsclen(msg) + 1;

    LPTSTR newBuffer = (LPTSTR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, newSize); // malloc()

    // Do the copy and concat
    if (*buffer == NULL)
        _tcscpy(newBuffer, msg); // strcpy()
    else
    {
        _tcscpy(newBuffer, *buffer);
        _tcscat(newBuffer, msg); // strcat()
        // release old buffer
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, *buffer); // free()
    }

    // store new pointer
    *buffer = newBuffer;
}
```

Tests:

```
LPTSTR test = NULL;
add_to_buffer(&test, _T("User:\r\n"));
add_to_buffer(&test, _T("42"));
```

First call to `add_to_buffer` works. However, the second function call causes an exception at `HeapFree`. I'm sure this is a problem about pointers, but I do not understand how to fix it.

Is it a good method? How to fix my exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are compiling the code as multi-byte application this line

```
LPTSTR newBuffer = (LPTSTR)HeapAlloc(
  GetProcessHeap(), 
  HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 
  newSize
);
```

might allocate to few memory.

To fix this use:

```
LPTSTR newBuffer = (LPTSTR)HeapAlloc(
  GetProcessHeap(), 
  HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 
  newSize * sizeof(*newBuffer)
);
```

Besides this and the fact that the code lacks error checking for system calls the code looks fine.

However, to simplify things one can use [`HeapReAlloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of the combination of `HeapAlloc()` and `HeapFree()`.

If the program crashes anyway this might due to the memory management already being mashed up before this actual crash you observe.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Could you give me an example with `HeapReAlloc()` in my function `add_to_buffer` ?

Comment: @user3748455: I'm looking forward to comment on your proposal how you'd do it, that you'd post in another question, which you are free to link from this question. Ok? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your program is unicode-enabled, you're not allocating enough memory - because string length (in symbols) and string size (in bytes) don't match.

If it isn't, I don't see reason of using non-standard-C types over standard ones. It shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: I think I allocate enough memory (_tcsclen is a wide-character version of strlen if the program is unicode-enabled; _tcsclen and strlen behave identically otherwise). I use the WinAPI, my program is supported only by a Windows OS. I think the problem comes from the `free` function call.

Comment: You really don't get it. If unicode is enabled, your characters isn't one-byte-wide. Length and size becomes completely different terms (was the same with single-byte encoding). You using length as if it is size, - and it is not enough. strcpy then exceeds your buffer size, corrupting heap structure and much much later free cannot live with it.