# How can I concatenate char pointers with the + operator in C?

Tags: c, operator-overloading, concatenation

Is there any way to concatenate char pointers with the + operator in c?

I know that I can concatenate strings with strcopy() and strcat()

[How to concat two char * in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746866/how-to-concat-two-char-in-c)

[Concatenate two char* strings in a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468229/concatenate-two-char-strings-in-a-c-program)

But how can I concatenate char pointers with the `+ operator` in c?(Maybe operator overloading works but I don't know how to overload + operator to concatenate char pointers)

Comment: You can't......

Comment: There is no operator overloading in c. You simply can't.

Comment: even in c++ it isnt possible (at least not trivially) to overload for pointers

Comment: C does not define the `+` operator for string concatenation, and you can't overload it to do so.  You *have* to use `strcat` or an equivalent function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in C. C does not support operator overloading.