# strcat() concatenating to two strings

Tags: c, string, while-loop, switch-statement, strcat

I am trying to concatenate a card ex."10" "1" "A" to the string "pile". This is a very simplified version of Blackjack, so it is not concerned with the suits of the cards and deals one card at a time.

However when I run it, it adds the card to a pile string that was not passed into the method.

I made a minimal recreation of the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int placeCard(char *pile, char *card)
{
    //removed code for minimal recreation of problem
    //no piles finished
        strcat(pile, card);
        return 0;
}

int main()
{    
    char card[4];

    char pile1[] = "";
    char pile2[] = "";
    char pile3[] = "";
    char pile4[] = "";
    char pile5[] = "";

    char faces[13][4] = {" 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", " 10", " J", " Q", " K", " A"};

    while(1)
    {
        // print current state of game
        printf("Pile (1): %-20s \n",    pile1);
        printf("Pile (2): %-20s \n",    pile2);
        printf("Pile (3): %-20s \n",    pile3);
        printf("Pile (4): %-20s \n",    pile4);
        printf("Pile (5): %-20s \n\n",  pile5);

        //get random card
        int j = rand() % 52;
        //convert to string
        strcpy(card, faces[j/4]);

        printf("Drawn Card: %s\n\n", card);

        printf("Which pile to place card in? ");
        //assume valid input (1-5) for minmal reproduction of error
        int userPileChoice;
        scanf("%d", &userPileChoice);
        switch (userPileChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                placeCard(pile1, card);
                break;
            case 2:
                placeCard(pile2, card);
                break;
            case 3:
                placeCard(pile3, card);
                break;
            case 4:
                placeCard(pile4, card);
                break;
            case 5:
                placeCard(pile5, card);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the output

```
Pile (1):                      
Pile (2):                      
Pile (3):                      
Pile (4):                      
Pile (5):                      

Drawn Card:  J

Which pile to place card in? 1
Pile (1):  J                   
Pile (2): J                    
Pile (3):                      
Pile (4):                      
Pile (5):                      

Drawn Card:  7

Which pile to place card in?
```

I was thinking it could possibly be the switch case inside the while loop and break is messing it up somehow, but I tried researching it and didn't see anything wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to post the code where you define the piles 1 to 5

Comment: This is not enough to reproduce the problem, and also it seems like you have not tried to remove everything that is not needed. Please create a [mre]. And post output as text, not as pictures.

Comment: OT: using arrays could make your code much simpler.

Comment: `memset(pile, 0, sizeof(pile));` looks fishy. `sizeof(pile)` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: understand should have done that first my apologies will write that now and edit post when done

Comment: Please provide plain text output as text inside your question. No need to provide graphics and make people follow some links.

Comment: Thank you for the criticism, rewrote the code with just enough to recreate the problem and changed the output to text.

Comment: `char pile1[] = "";`: in `pile1` there is space for exactly 0 characters. Read again the chapter dealing with strings inyour C text book. You would rather need something like `char pile1[100] = "";`, then you' d have room for 99 chars + the NUL terminator.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, thanks a lot, thats the solution, now I just feel bad for wasting space on SO for a basic mistake like this.

Comment: @T.Dakin be aware that the usage of `sizeof` in your original code is probably wrong,  for the length of a string you need the `strlen` function. And `memset` is probably unnecessary too, `*pile = 0`  is enough for emptying a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `char pile1[] = "";` will allocate an array of size 1, which is only enough for the NUL terminator, which means that it is essentially useless. Do the following change to the code:

```
#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    char card[4];

    char pile1[SIZE] = "";
    // Same for the rest
```

This will solve your problem. But I recommend reading about dangers with `strcat`. Here is a related post: [strcat Vs strncat - When should which function be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491038/6699433)
And it will work

Comment: Thanks thats the solution. I do wonder then what is happening when I pass it a string of size 0 and how strcat is modifying the other strings next to the original, in a different method no less.